# The shape of the hill is given by given by the function. If you walk due to south-west direction, will you start to descending or ascending?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The shape of the hill is given by given by the function

$$f(x,y) = 5000 - 0.001x^2 - 0.04y^2$$

Where $x$ and $y$ are measured in meters, and the positive $x$-axis points east; positive $y$-axis,
north. Suppose that you are standing at a point $(500,300, 4390)$.

a. If you walk due to south-west direction, will you start to descending or
ascending? At what rate?

b. In what direction should you move in order to ascend at the greatest rate? At what rate?

I'm completely lost on this one, not sure where to start or what to do. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Looks like you fall and kill yourself! The height of the hill at $x=500,y=300$ is 1150, so you seem to be 3240 above ground.

Comment: We need to know what your context is. Do you know about directional derivatives? gradient?

Comment: I have only the most basic understanding of gradients and directional derivatives. I would really appreciate a step by step explanation of this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'm assuming the actual equation is:

$f(x,y) = 5000 - 0.001x^2 - 0.004y^2$

Otherwise the point $(500,300, 4390)$ is not a solution to $f(x,y)$.

To find the rate of change in a given direction, you need to find the directional derivative in that direction. Here is a good intro with examples: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DirectionalDeriv.aspx

Step 1: Get the partial derivatives of the function $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$

$f_x= -0.002x$
$f_y= -0.008y$

Step 2: Determine the unit vector in the direction you want

Let's call the unit vector

$u = (a,b)$

where $\sqrt{{a^2}+{b^2}} = 1$

For question (a) you are heading due south-west and hence your unit vector will be

$u = (-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$

Step 3: Write the directional derivative

$D_uf(x,y) = af_x + bf_y$

For question (a) this becomes

$D_uf(x,y) = (-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})(-0.002x) + (-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})(-0.008y)$

Inserting $(x,y) = (500, 300)$ you get

$D_uf(500,300) = \frac{3.4}{\sqrt{2}}$

So the answer to question (a) is that you are ascending and at the rate given above.

For question (b), you don't know which direction you must go and hence which unit vector you must use. One way to solve this is to use the unit vector

$u = (cos(\theta), sin(\theta))$

You can then write the directional derivative which, when you plug in $(x,y) = (500, 300)$, will give an equation depending only on $\theta$. Differentiate this equation and find for what $\theta$ it is $0$. The answer to (b) then becomes:

$\theta = arctan(2.4) + \pi$
Rate = 2.6

Comment: Incredibly helpful, thank you! I just have one question. Where did the $\pi$ come from in question b? I'm setting up the directional derivative as

$cos(\theta)+2.4sin(\theta)$

Then solving for $\theta$ but I'm just getting:

$arctan(2.4) = \theta$

Comment: The directional derivative is $-cos(\theta)-2.4sin(\theta)$. If you plug in $\theta = arctan(2.4)$ you get the value $-2.6$ which is the maximum descending rate, not maximum ascending rate. You therefore need to use the other solution to $tan(\theta) = 2.4$ in the range $0$ to $2\pi$. Remember that the full solution to  $tan(\theta) = 2.4$ is $\theta = arctan(2.4)$ +/- $n\pi$.